# Labeling on SciDraw figure

Tags: scidraw, levelscheme

Anyone still use `SciDraw`?

For those still reading, I have a multipanel figure and I would like to label each X-axis differently.

In `LevelScheme`, I would use `ScaledLabel[{.5, 0}, "Distance (m)", Offset -> {0, 2.75}]` in the appropriate panel, but `LevelScheme` doesn't like 13.3.1.

My attempt is

```
Figure[
 Multipanel[{
   FigurePanel[{
     (* stuff*)
     FigLabel[Scaled[{.5, 0}], "Distance (s)", TextOffset -> {0, -2}]
     }, {1, 1},
    XPlotRange -> {0, 1000}];
   FigurePanel[{
     (* still more stuff *)
     }, {2, 1}];
   FigurePanel[{
     FigLabel[{0, 1}, "Time (ms)", TextOffset -> {-1, 0}],
     FigLabel[{0, aposn[[#]]}, ToString@ggate[[#]], 
        Color -> acolr[[#]], TextOffset -> {-1, 0}] & /@ 
      Range[Length@ggate]
     }, {1, 2},
    YPlotRange -> {0, 1.1},
    XPlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> False, PanelLetter -> None];
   },
  Dimensions -> {2, 2},
  PanelLetter -> Automatic,
  PanelLetterDirection -> Vertical,
  XPlotRange -> {{-1000, 1000}, {0, 1}},
  YPlotRange -> {{-.25, 1}, {-1000, 100}},
  XPanelSizes -> {1, .1},
  YPanelGaps -> {.2}, 
  XPanelGaps -> {.025},
  YTicks -> {LinTicks[-1, 1, .1, 5], LinTicks[-1000, 500, 200, 5]},
  YFrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(B\), \(A\)]\) (nT)", "RL (m)"},
  XTicks -> {LinTicks[-1000, 1000, 200, 5], None},
  XFrameLabel -> {"Easting (m)", None}
  ],
 CanvasSize -> {A4LENGTH, A4WIDTH},
 CanvasMargin -> .95,
 Style -> "Base"]
```

The `FigLabel[...]` line in panel 1 does not work.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

20 minutes of flailing around later ...

The solution is to use the code:

```
    FigurePanel[{
  (* stuff*)
  }, {1, 1},
 ShowFrameLabel -> {True, True, False, False},
 XFrameLabel -> "Distance (m)",
 XShowTickLabels -> True,
 XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1000, 200, 5],
 XPlotRange -> {0, 1000}]
```

Thanks for your patience.